# a problem with the jquery color picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors

i have this jquery colorpicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ , everything is working fine but i dnt seem to know how when the page is loaded i want the colorpicker to be on a default chosen color i.e black

i have a working code http://jsfiddle.net/SpmuV/5/

p.s. the default one is white, but i want to change it to black. thanks for this :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I misunderstood your question.  From your example

http://jsfiddle.net/SpmuV/14/

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#colPick').css('background-color', '#000000');
$("#colPick").ColorPicker({
    color: '#000000',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colPick').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
    }
}); 

});
```

Ok, notice the OnChange event delegate, your selector is wrong, you need to change it to '#colPick'.

And since we are hard coding the default value to black for the color picker, we can do the same for our selector control with `$('#colPick').css('background-color', '#000000');`

Comment: i think the color property, only determines where the color os located when the color popup is shown, if you get my drift!!

Comment: sorry i still dnt get this, could add it to the jsfiddle above, i would love to see how it works, sorrry :((

Comment: I didn't understand what you were asking before, I've adjusted my answer accordingly, it seems to work well.

Comment: oh yeh thats true, so where would i put the `$('#colPick').css('background-color', '#000000');`, in ther onchange function

Comment: you don't, have a look at the code I posted, or the jsfiddle example to see how it works.  You need to do 2 things, 1 set the default color for your '#colPick', 2 when setting up the onchange handler, fix your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color?
color: '#0000ff'-> color: '#000000',

Comment: @lucas, that sets the location of the color on popup only, thanks!!